# Can't run a basic test with casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm trying to submit a form with `casperjs`, a simple task according to the documentation.
However, it just doesn't work.

Here is the code :

```
casper.test.begin('Logging in', nbTests, function(test) {
    casper.start(A_SERVER);
    casper.then(function() {
    this.fill('form', {
        'username': GOOD_LOGIN,
        'password': GOOD_PASSWORD}, true);
this.waitUntilVisible('.success');
this.waitForText('Successful login', function (){
    casper.test.assertExists('.success');    
});
    });

    casper.run(function(){
        test.done();
        this.exit();
    });
});
```

However, doing so returns this :

```
# Logging in
PASS Found an element matching: form
FAIL Redirection to dashboard after successfull login.
#    type: assertExists
#    file: /home/fx/SRC/server/tests_integration/ti_login.js:28
#    code: test.assertExists('.success', "Redirection to dashboard after successfull login.");
#    subject: false
#    selector: ".success"
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/ from frame with URL file:////etc/local/bin/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

The first trouble is, of course the failure. However, I'm also worried about the other warning (wich occurs randomly).
Would you know something about this ?

EDIT : I refactored the code, now it works. However, I don't understand why. Would somebody be kindly enought to explain the problem ?

Comment: FYI to avoid the "Unsafe JavaScript" warning, load your file using `127.0.0.1:8000` as you seem to already having a server running.

Comment: I can't do so, it's something managed by `casperjs` itself.

Comment: What version of CasperJS and PhantomJS are you using?

Comment: CasperJS : 1.1.0-DEV;


PhantomJS : 1.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I was just badly using `casperjs`. Here is the functionnal code I managed to produce :

```
casper.test.begin('Logging in', nbTests, function(test) {
    casper.start(A_SERVER + A_LOGIN);

    casper.then(function goodInput(){
    this.fill('form', {
        'username': GOOD_LOGIN,
        'password': GOOD_PASSWORD}, true);

    this.waitUntilVisible('#id_file_field');
    this.waitForText('Successful login', function (){
        casper.test.assertExists('#id_file_field', "Login successful");    
    });

    casper.run(function(){
        test.done();
    });
});
```

However, I still don't know what cause the XHR problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running CasperJS like this:

```
casperjs --web-security=false test test.js
```

This will allow cross-domain XHR, which may be useful in your case.